# Using h1:after, added text doesn't wrap with the rest?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm having this problem. I want to add a word in a different color on the same line as my h1. I am using h1:after to add the word and style it red.

The problem is that when I resize the window, the word doesn't wrap in the same way that adding the word without styling will.

This is the pen: https://codepen.io/sidiousvic/pen/VBeRdM

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Iceberg;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

h1:after {
  content: "(RED)";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vinyl Player (Red)</h1>
```

As you can see, I left the two options on: the (RED) word inside the h1 tag and the same as an added content in h1:after. If you resize the window, you can see the white text wrapping together nicely, and the red, added text straying a bit.

Can it be done? I've tried a lot of stuff, including  and  inside the h1, same problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's because the flex property ...enable the wrap `flex-wrap:wrap`

Answer (score 2):

`display: flex` forces children to be displayed side-by-side (respecting their `min-width` properties), which your `h1` and it's `:after` don't have. Removing it falls back to default `display: inline`.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Snippet

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Iceberg;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

h1:after {
  content: "(RED)";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vinyl Player (Red)</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check out that guide! （╹◡╹）

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: flex;` property. Not sure if you need it.